# How can I reduce the number of if statements in my 2D numpy code?

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I have a numpy ndarray (`M`) holding a 2D symmetric matrix that contains N x N numbers (N is an integer), for example

```
[[1. 2. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 1. 2. 0. 0. 2. 2.]
 [0. 2. 1. 2. 0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 2. 1. 2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 2. 1. 2. 0.]
 [2. 2. 0. 0. 2. 1. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 2. 1.]]
```

I want to examine that: set item i,j in M to 0 where j in i+1, i+2, i+3 to zero in M

I have this code, that do this:

```
for i in range(len(M)):
     for j in range(len(M)):
        if M[i, j] != 0:
            if j == len(M) - 3:
                M[i, j+2] = 0
                M[i, j+1] = 0
            elif j == len(M) - 2:
                M[i, j+1] = 0
            elif j == len(M) - 1:
                   continue
            else:
                M[i, j + 3] = 0
                M[i, j + 2] = 0
                M[i, j + 1] = 0
        else:
            continue
```

It works pretty well, but I want to reduce my if statements. I read about `M[i,j:j+3]`, but I don't really know how to use it.

I'm waiting the following output matrix:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]]
```

Comment: You haven't defined what `dist` is. Please make a better effort of explaining what you're trying to do. Also share expected output

Comment: Thank you. I forget to change dist to M :) i corrected :)
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 0.]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for i in range(len(M)):
     for j in range(len(M)):
        if M[i, j] != 0:
            M[i, (j+1):(j+4)] = 0
print (M)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]]
```

Comment: It almost good. With my example works well. But if i had a longer matrix it doesnt do what i want. I want to reach that if I had a not 0 value change the three values next to it to 0. For example: 

    `[[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
    [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
    [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
    [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
    [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
    [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
    [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]]`

to

    `[[2 0 0 0 2 0 0 ]
    [2 0 0 0 2 0 0 ]
    [2 0 0 0 2 0 0 ]
    [2 0 0 0 2 0 0 ]
    [2 0 0 0 2 0 0 ]
    [2 0 0 0 2 0 0 ]
    [2 0 0 0 2 0 0 ]]`

Comment: @DavidFetter, you did not state all your requirements up-front. I've updated the code now, for your new requirement for bigger matrix. Pls check